# How to install a windows service from a Windows 8 store app?

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows

I have a windows store app "MyApp" in place. The app reads from a file "MyFile" that is written by a windows service "Myservice". I want to install and start the service when the app is first installed in the system. Is there a way to do that?

I thought of a way around where both the app and the service can be packaged as an exe and can be installed together from a single "mysetup.exe" but did not get any ways to do that too.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

P.S: I am using C# to code.

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure you can't install a windows service through a Windows 8 Store App.
But, what is your service supposed to do ? Can't you do it through a BackgroundTask ?

Comment: If that could be done the Store Apps sandboxing will be useless...

Comment: @Aymeric No the background task wont suffice because i am using the same service to interact with some external hardware as well through USB.

Comment: @Gusman Is there a way to package the two as a windows installer, so that the app need not install the service.

Comment: @vito that's the same case, if the Store allowed to distribute another exe with your app then sandboxing will be useless. The only way comes to my mind is to ask the user to install an external package which will be downloaded from somewhere (your app shows a form with instructions on how to install, launches a browser and then the user installs the package)

Comment: you should separate them into two. one is store app. another is desktop application.

Comment: Ya currently I am doing that only. An app package with the app and a download link to the executable in the app itself. I am looking for a way to reduce this extra effort on the part of the user to install the windows service.